# I got the error when calling a function with param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
onTypeSelect (str) {
        this.setState({taskType: str})
    }

<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onTypeSelect('type1').bind(this)}>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this3.onTypeSelect('type1).bind').

Can anyone help me? I am a beginner of react-native.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
onTypeSelect (str) {
    this.setState({taskType: str})
}

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.onTypeSelect('type1'); }} />
```

When you .bind(this), *you need to pass a function and not the return value of a function, in this case, `undefined`*. This way it works because the function is called from inside the component scope thus making `this` a valid reference.

Another way to fix the problem is by using bind this way:

```
this.onTypeSelect.bind(this, 'type1')
```

EDIT: Thanks for the comments and other replies, I added the information for sake of completion and information.
[Alexander T.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367138/alexander-t), [Bartek F.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7518718/bartek-fryzowicz)

Comment: You code works but explanation is not correct. *When you .bind(this), the scope is the current HTMLDOMElement,* - it's not true. `this` points to the component during binding. The problem was that  `bind` should be used on function itself, not the result returned by function. Please see @Alexander .answer for detailed explanation

Answer (score 2):

Based on [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) docs, you have to pass arguments to `.bind` like so

```
this.onTypeSelect.bind(this, 'type1')
```

> `fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])`

In your example, you call method

```
this.onTypeSelect('type1')
```

the method returns *result*(in this case *result* will be `undefined`), and you are trying to apply `.bind` to *result*(`undefined`)

```
undefined.bind(this)
```

However [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) exists only in `Function` object, that's why you get the error.